# Excel - Count how many days cell contain certain text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is it possible for Excel/ VBA to count how many days cell contained certain text?

For example:
Cell A2 contained the letter "a" for 3 days then was changed to the letter "b" for 5 days?

If so, how would you go about this?
[image: example]

(Note that the data in D2 and E2 are purely fabricated, but is the output I'm looking to achieve.)

Sorry if I am posting in the wrong place. I've searched the web for examples of something like this but cannot find any in order to test out.

Update 21/02/2022:
@EngineerToast If I am auditing multiple rows but only want to look one specific row how do I go about this? I can see the AuditTrail shows the range A2 so is there a way to capture data from different cells?

[image]

I figure it's got something to do with amending the existing formula you've provided?

```
=LET(value,E2,firstDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!F:F,value),lastDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!E:E,value),IF(firstDate=0,"",IF(lastDate=0,TODAY(),lastDate)-firstDate))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Yes, it's possible. Please edit your post with the details of your data and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to keep track of a single cell and its changes over time. There is no way to do this natively. However, you can use VBA to keep track of changes and then use a formula to evaluate that audit trail.

Both of those steps are complicated so this answer is complicated. Take a stab at the implementation and, if something doesn't work right, try to figure out why before you come back with specific questions.

---

First, you need to setup a worksheet to house the audit trail. I named mine "AuditTrail" with no spaces. You should probably also add a header row just so you can read it more easily later. You'll what I added in the first row in a screenshot later.

---

Second, this VBA code should be pasted into the module for whatever sheet has the cell you want to watch.  Open VBA by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (there are other ways, too). Double-click on the sheet name to open it's module, and paste the code. For me, the sheet name was "Sheet1". You can see that Excel assigns a code name for each sheet but also shows you the name you've given it that you see in Excel. For instance, the sheet I named "AuditTrail" has the code name "Sheet2". Look for the name you've given your sheet in the parentheses.

[image: VBA Modules]

After you paste this code, be sure to double-check the two values at the beginning and change them as needed.

```vb
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        
        ' You have to change / check at least these values:
        Const addressOfCellToWatch As String = "A2"
        Const sheetNameForAuditTrail As String = "AuditTrail"
        
        ' The rest of code will work as-is
        Dim rangeToWatch As Range
        Dim newActiveCell As Range
        Dim oldValue
        Dim lastUsedRow As Long
        Dim auditDataRange As Range
    
        ' Use this method if you only want to watch one range
        Set rangeToWatch = Range(addressOfCellToWatch)
        
        ' Check if the Target (the cell that changed) was part of the range to watch
        If Not Intersect(Target, rangeToWatch) Is Nothing Then
            ' Undo the change, get the old value, then redo the change
            ' Not necessary but you may want to keep track of it
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Set newActiveCell = ActiveCell
            Application.Undo
            oldValue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo   'Yes, this is a redo. I know it seems backwards.
            newActiveCell.Activate
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            
            ' Compile the results
            ' The array order is (time, sheet name, cell address, user name, previous value, new value)
            auditdata = Array(Now, Target.Parent.Name, Target.Address, Environ("username"), oldValue, Target.Value)
            
            ' Find where we're going to paste these results
            With Worksheets(sheetNameForAuditTrail)
                ' Find the last used row
                lastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                
                ' Define the cells we're going to use for the audit data
                Set auditDataRange = .Range("A1:F1").Offset(lastUsedRow)
                
                ' Store the data
                auditDataRange = auditdata
            End With
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

---

As you edit the cell you want to keep track of, the audit trail will fill in with data that looks like this:

[image: AuditTrail]

---

Now that you have all that fancy data, you can use a formula to pull the results. You didn't discuss how you wanted to handle it if the value goes from `a` to `b` then back to `a` again. I've written my formula to pull how long it was a certain value the most recent time that it was that value. If you want the total number of days that something has been a certain value, that'll be more complicated.

```
=LET(value,E2,firstDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!F:F,value),lastDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!E:E,value),IF(firstDate=0,"",IF(lastDate=0,TODAY(),lastDate)-firstDate))
```

The LET() functions lets you assign values to variables and then reference the variable names later on. It can make messy formulas easier to read. Here's the breakdown of each of those values:

- `value,E2` defines the value we seek in the audit trail. For instance, `E2` could contain simply the text `a` and the formula will search for `a` in the audit trail.
- `firstDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!F:F,value)` finds the most recent date that the cell was changed ***to*** the value. This will be 0 if it's never been changed to that value.
- `lastDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!E:E,value)` finds the most recent date that the cell was changed ***from*** the value. This will be 0 if it's never been changed from that value. It may be less than `firstDate` if, for instance, it was `a` then `b` and now it's `a` again. It'll find the "a→b" date from before the "b→a" date.
- `IF(firstDate=0,"",` catches the times when it's never been changed to the value.
- `IF(lastDate=0,TODAY(),lastDate)` catches the times when it's never been changed *from* the value and substitutes today's date instead. IE, how long has it been the value that it currently is.
- `-firstDate` subtracts the *to* date from the *from* date (or today's date, depending on the previous step).

This returns decimal numbers but you can apply rounding as desired.

[image: Results]

Comment: Exhaustive! Alternative: if you find Target.Parent.Name and Target.Address in auditDataRange (from bottom to top), then you can get the previous value of the audited cell without Undo-Redo

Comment: Wow! Absolutely love how much detail you've gone into here within such a short timeframe. It may take me a moment to work my way through but fully appreciate your support, stranger.

Comment: @JohnSUN The Worksheet_Change event fires *after* the value has already been changed. How can I use the worksheet name and cell address to get the value from before the change?

Comment: @EngineerToast We know the new value - this is the current value after the event is fired. The old value was written in the last change of this sheet-cell to the log-sheet (if it ever happened). It is there that I propose to find the old value of this event (and timestamp if necessary).

Comment: @JohnSUN Ah! I see, yes. For that matter, you could drop that column entirely from the output since the data is there. You are right that it's an alternative but I would still opt for the more direct approach rather than rely on the audit trail not being messed up.

Comment: @EngineerToast If I am auditing multiple rows but only want to look one specific row how do I go about this? I can see the AuditTrail shows the range A2 so is there a way to capture data from different cells?

Comment: @TM3000 You can have it keep track of any cell(s) you want. This line is what defines the range to keep track of in the audit tab: `Set rangeToWatch = Range(addressOfCellToWatch)`. Change that line to reference some other range. For instance, if you want to watch rows 3 and 7, you could do this: `Set rangeToWatch = Union(Range("3:3"),Range("7:7"))`. There are lots of ways to reference ranges. Use the one you're comfortable with.