# Count time cells contain certain text using data from VBA Audit Trail output

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Following my previous query [Excel - Count how many days cell contain certain text](https://superuser.com/questions/1702384/excel-count-how-many-days-cell-contain-certain-text/1702407#1702407) which was answered by Engineer Toast,
I'm looking to capture how long a specific range has remained in a certain status utilising the AuditTrail created by VBA.

For example:
Looking at **Image 1 - Sheet1**, within C3 how long has B3 contained the text "a", then within D3 how long has B3 contained the text "b" etc, ignoring changes made to B4 and B5 so essentially only looking up changes made within **Image 2 - AuditTrail** cells containing the reference $B$3.

Engineer Toast mentioned I could amend the VBA code but then this would create multiple sheets of an AuditTrail, which is not what I'm after.

**Image 1 - Sheet1**

[image: sheet1]

**Image 2 - AuditTrail**

[image: AuditTrail]

All I've got so far is the following code which is far from being correct. IF cells C2:C1000 of the AuditTrail sheet contain the text "$B$3" then complete the formula provided by Engineer Toast

```
=LET(value,E2,IF((AuditTrail!C2:C1000="$B$3"),firstDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!F:F,value),lastDate,MAXIFS(AuditTrail!A:A,AuditTrail!E:E,value),IF(firstDate=0,"",IF(lastDate=0,TODAY(),lastDate)-firstDate))
```

**Image 3 - Expected outcome**
[image: Final]
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work?

```
=SUM((A2:A12)*(C2:C12="$B$3")*(E2:E12="a"))-SUM((A2:A12)*(C2:C12="$B$3")*(F2:F12="a"))
```

The question is how long does $B$3 say equal to the value a in total? Manually this is:

```
(A6-A2) + (A8-A7) + (A10-A9)
```

which can be written

```
(A6+A8+A10) - (A2+A7+A9)
```

or

```
(sum of all $B$3 rows where old value is "a") - (sum of all $B$3 rows where new value is "a")
```

The only problem I see so far, is if we have unmatched pairs, i.e. in the begin we didn't log the cell becoming "a" (no new value, but one old value) or the other way round, $B$3 is still "a" (one new value but no old value). In the first case your answer will be much larger than usual (>40000) and in the latter negative ~40000.

If this is a problem, you could put if statements and either add or subtract the first old value or the last new value.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  Your formula of =SUM((A2:A12)*(C2:C12="$B$3")*(E2:E12="a"))-SUM((A2:A12)*(C2:C12="$B$3")*(F2:F12="a")) gives a value of around -40000, how do you convert that to number of days, hours and minutes?