# Excel Formula to display date when cells are filled in

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table and I need a excel formula that says the following:

If Cells C1, E1 and F1 are filled out, than today's date will appear. However if  Cells C1, E1 and F1 are not filled out, than the date will be D1.

Just a note, the value in the cells are a range between words, numbers and dates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What should happen to the date that was calculated yesterday? Should it change to today's date? If you use worksheet formulas, you cannot create a date stamp with a formula, because =today() will always show the current date, i.e. it will always change. If you need the date to stay the same, you need VBA.

Comment: @ExcelQuestion ,,, I think your question needs more clarification,,, like in which cell you want the formula,,, and if C1:E1 will be blank then what date to be entered as you have written "the date will be D1" !! Please [edit] the post & share some sample data.

Comment: Yes, I agree with teylyn. You need to provide more details. If the date of "Today"  is dynamically updated, it is recommended to refer to Preston Maness's good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (you'll need to remove the comment lines that start with `'` though to place this in the formula box):

```
=IF(
    ' if or is true, the we failed the condition.
    ' if or is false, then we met the condition.
    ' so flip with NOT
    NOT(
        ' if any of these are blank, OR will return true
        OR(
            ISBLANK(C1),
            ISBLANK(E1),
            ISBLANK(F1)
        )
    ),
    ' we met the condition. use today's date
    TODAY(),
    ' we did not meet the condition. Use D1
    D1
)
```

You'll need to format the output column as a date though (column G in this case).

[image]

Comment: .... but that formula will show tomorrow's date tomorrow ...

Comment: @teylyn indeed, but tomorrow will still fulfill the same condition that all cells be filled in, and should then correctly reflect tomorrow's date :) ExcelQuestion, if you want to *lock-in* and log the date that the cells were filled in, this is a different requirement and would require VBA code. Here is a nice recent question on SU which addresses logging dates when cells are changed: https://superuser.com/questions/1702384/excel-count-how-many-days-cell-contain-certain-text/1702407#1702407

Comment: @Preston does excel allow the use of comments in a formula? Or would the OP need to delete all the text preceeded by the *`*

Comment: @Mobus the comments would need to be deleted.